# Autoresizing composition of elements

Tags: css

I have a lot of elements I need to align in a same line, except for the first label, and I really need the select width to adapt to the window size (on resizing). E.g.
[image]

I can't change the HTML structure, because it is auto-generated by a framework, but I can change the CSS code or even add some classes in the html.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span>
        <span class="inline">&nbsp;</span>
        <label class="block">Pets</label>
        <span class="inline">
            <select>
                <option value="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
                <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="inline">*</span>
        <span class="inline">
            <span >&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>
            <button>
                <span>Configure</span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <span >*</span>
        <span >
            <span >&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I tryed a lot of things with element inspection, especially the display property with table and table-cell values, but I can't get the elements in the same line and the select with auto width resizing. I can't also align the first span with the select in the same line...

```
.input-group {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.inline
{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 33px;
}
.block{
    display: block;
}
```

Can you give me a hand?
Thanks a lot!
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/29qstLq8/1/

Comment: Something like this? ---------------> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/29qstLq8/10/).

Comment: No, Look at the image I added: http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/29qstLq8/11/

Comment: The idea is having the label separated. And when you resize the window, to resize the components but having them in the same line

Comment: Okay this is the closest I could get :---------------->>> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/29qstLq8/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest thing that I've gotten so far. My code makes use of `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` to achieve something close to what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/29qstLq8/14/

Comment: But the first span (with no content) is still in a different row with the select, and I need them in the same. And the select is no auto resizing it's value to fit the window width

Comment: so you want the `<span class="inline">&nbsp;</span>` to be in the same row as your select span? I updated my fiddle to handle autoresizing of the select box based on the window width

Comment: Nope, I need the label and the first blank span in the first line. Everything else in the second and the select to fit all the free space in line 2. I put another classnames in the html so you can understand better: http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/29qstLq8/7/

Comment: ah got it. gimme a little bit and i'll fix my answer

Comment: Thank you a lot!! :) I'm going crazy with this!!

Comment: To have the configure button be a static width while the `select` changes width based on the window AND we can't change the html is a little tricky. Do you have any requirements in terms of which browser versions this has to handle?

Comment: Sorry, you can change the style classnames in html, or add new ones, but not the structure f the html

Comment: i updated my answer. can you check to see if that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of table cell, you should use `display: inline-block`.  This puts everything in a line if there is enough space:

http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/29qstLq8/8/

Comment: Well... you get the same result as me. The real challenge is I need to adjust the width of the select element and align the label with the first blank span

Comment: I adjusted the width of the `<select>` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/29qstLq8/6/).  Is that what you want?

Comment: Nope, I need the label + the first blank span in the first line. Everything else in the second and the select to fit all the free space in line 2. I added another classnames in the html so it can be easy to understand (better than my english haha): jsfiddle.net/gal007/29qstLq8/7

Comment: The idea is the image I used in the description

Comment: I adjusted the width of the `<select>` AND the `<button>` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/29qstLq8/8/). Is that what you want?

Comment: Something like that, but the controls doesnt fit when you change the window size. And the two first elements are not in the same line

Answer (score -1):

Did you try floating instead of table-cell?

```
.inline
{
    float:left;
    height: 33px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7c97xg2/

Comment: But you changed the elements order

Comment: I added an image in description